# Calculate apprx. SVG Ellipse length? (calculate apprx. ellipse circumference with Javascript)

Tags: javascript, math, svg, ellipse

I have an SVG element like so:

```
<ellipse class="solidLine" cx="649.9" cy="341.09" rx="39.49" ry="8.41"/>
```

and I need to find its `length` so that I can animate it's `dashoffset` to have it being "drawn".

I've done these calculations with the following tags: `line` `polyline` `circle` `path`, but now I need to calculate the length of an ellipse and I'm a little.. stuck. I've done some googling and can't seem to find a Javascript way to calculate the circumference of an ellipse.

Any help? Here's my function format so far:

```
const getEllipseLength = (ellipse) => {
    let rx = ellipse.getAttribute('rx');
    let ry = ellipse.getAttribute('ry');
    let totalLength = //function to calculate ellipse circumference using radius-x (rx) and radius-y (ry) here!
    return totalLength;
};
```

Thanks!

**edit:** if there's a quick way to do this that isn't 100% accurate (*but close*) that would be fine also. I just need to get in the ballpark of the actual circumference in order to do a smooth animation.

**edit 2:** I think using [this](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2013/05/05/ramanujan-circumference-ellipse/) equation will give me a close estimate without having to delve into Euler's series shenanigans.. gonna translate it into Javascript and see if it works.

Comment: I'm guessing based on this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Circumference that the answer to your question is not going to be something simple.

Comment: On the other hand, this site seems to have a JS-based approach :  http://www.csgnetwork.com/circumellipse.html

Comment: the site above uses:  `ellipse    = ((Math.sqrt(.5 * ((len * len) + (wid * wid)))) * (PI * 2)) / 2;`

Comment: hmm, that site actually gave me a value of ~89 when i ran with my two test options when the real value was ~166. think something's broken on there :c

Comment: @shanling that site actually gives 179.38. Unlike Google's tool, they use the axis, not the radius, so you'll have to multiply your rx and ry by 2.

Comment: each ellipse circumference approximation has limits usually eccentricity interval on which it works.

Answer (score 3):

Alright this was actually easier than I thought.. welp.

Since I only needed an approximate length I translated [this](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2013/05/05/ramanujan-circumference-ellipse/) equation into Javascript and came up with this:

```
const getEllipseLength = (ellipse) => {
    let rx = parseInt(ellipse.getAttribute('rx'));
    let ry = parseInt(ellipse.getAttribute('ry'));
    let h = Math.pow((rx-ry), 2) / Math.pow((rx+ry), 2);
    let totalLength = (Math.PI * ( rx + ry )) * (1 + ( (3 * h) / ( 10 + Math.sqrt( 4 - (3 * h) )) ));
    return totalLength;
};
```

When used with `rx="39.49"` and `ry="8.41"` it gave me a value of `164.20811705227723`, and google tells me the actual circumference is about `166.79`. Not too bad, and just fine for SVG animation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround. Using this code:

```
<path 
d="
M cx cy
m -rx, 0
a rx,ry 0 1,1 (rx * 2),0
a rx,ry 0 1,1 -(rx * 2),0
"
/>
```

We can create a path that's similar to the ellipse. Then, it's just a matter of using `getTotalLength()`. Check the demo snippet (I'm using a different `cx` and `cy` just to save some SVG space):

```js
var length = document.getElementById("path").getTotalLength();
console.log(length)
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
 <path id="path" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" d="M 49.9, 41.09 m -39.49, 0 a 39.49,8.41 0 1,0 78.98,0 a 39.49,8.41 0 1,0 -78.98,0"/>
</svg>
```

It logs `166.82369995117188`, which is very close to `166.79` (the circumference calculated by Google's tool) .

Comment: Hmm, interesting! I have quite a few ellipses on this SVG so going through & changing them all would be a pain, but this would be good to know when creating a new SVG / a simpler one. Do you know if running getTotalLength() would be faster than the method I posted above?

Comment: I don't know, we can benchmark it. But I believe that in these modern browsers, if you don't have an astronomical number of ellipses, there difference should be negligible.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to change all of your ellipses to paths by hand... you can create a function to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that that approximation works good for circle-like ellipses and gives significant error for long ones (with high a/b ratio).

If you aware about the second case, use iterative [Gauss-Kummer approach](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Gauss-KummerSeries.html)

```
A = Pi * (a + b) * (1 + h^2/4 + h^4/64 + h^6/256...)
```

summing until next addend `h^k/2^m` becomes small enough

Answer (score 0):

Here's my best approximation for the ellipse perimeter:

```
e = (a - b) / a
P =  (1 - e) * ( * ((/2) * a + (2-(/2)) * b)) + (e * 4 * a)
```

```js
function getEllipseLength (ellipse) {
  let a = ellipse.getAttribute('rx');
  let b = ellipse.getAttribute('ry');
  if (a < b) {
    var t = a;
    a = b;
    b = t;
  }
  var hpi = Math.PI/2;
  var e = (a - b) / a; // e = 0 circle             or   1 = line
  return (1 - e) * (Math.PI * (hpi*a + (2-hpi)*b)) + (e * 4 * a);
}
```